# I recently upgraded to 16GB, now my computer is slower. What can I do?

Tags: memory, performance

I've recently upgraded my RAM to 16GB (4GB before the change), and I've noticed my computer runs slower than before. After the change, gaming reached higher FPS than ever and surfing the web was no issue, however, I had an issues where my computer was switching itself off spontaneously, which I managed to stop by giving my computer a quick maintenance sweep e.g. cleaning CPU fan, removing and fitting the RAM in again, etc. Now, my FPS in games has plummeted, even lower than before the change. I am unsure as to what has happened, or how I could change it, any advice would be brilliant.

Specs:

- AMD Radeon HD 7700 series,
- Intel(R)Pentium(R) CPU G840 @2.80GHz, 16GB RAM, 64-bit OS

Comment: overheat? are all fans working properly and temperatures of CPU/GPU?

Comment: Can you provide your motherboard model?

Comment: The tilte would be better with "The computer runs slower after a quick maintenance sweep e.g Cleaning CPU fan (NOT RAM related)".

Comment: Most likely, you didn't remount the heat sink correctly.

Comment: can you provide temp readings?

Answer (score 1):

Try to back to original RAM size and check if it back to normal.

Run `memtest86+` to check all memory. Be sure to wait until 2-3 full subsequent tests would complete successfully.(It would take a pretty long time, but it will ensure what problem is - hardware or software.)

Comment: @gronostaj Motherboard- MSI H61M-P31 (G3)

Comment: You will not loose anything if you will try to load computer with `memtest86+`. When you increased RAM size, you increase total loading for motherboard that cause more heat on motherboard elements (capacitors is number one candidates to die from it). You need to resolve problem by start testing most common issues. BTW, download `hwinfo` and check S.M.A.R.T status of HDD. If it going bad, it will slowdown computer a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would start from scratch.  Disconnect the power supply, clean everything and very carefully reassemble the pc with only one memory module.  If you removed or otherwise shifted your cpu heatsink then you should probably remove it again, clean it and reinstall it (using fresh thermal paste!)  If all goes well then you could add more memory modules one at a time.  Did you check the motherboard manufacturers website to see if the memory modules you are using are validated for use with that board?  Are you using a quality power supply with a high enough wattage?